# Gzip Mutliple files using single command

Tags: filenames, gzip

Want to Gzip my all the .csv files into a gzip file.

I am using this command.

```
gzip *.csv;
```

***Problem*** File contains '//' in its name that's why command is giving error.

**Error** : - '//File.csv' is not a directory or file.

So please suggest me what ways i can do this successfully.

one solution i thought.

```
gzip '//File1.csv' '//File2.csv' '//File3.csv'
```

Please suggest me if this is the right way to perform the same.

Comment: `/` is not a valid character in a filename in any *nix filesystem I have used. In fact, it's not even valid in Windows filesystems such as NTFS.

Comment: Its coming because we have some old legacy code. Best solution is change that but it can create a mess for us.

Comment: Agree with @jordanm - it's not possible to create a file with a '/' (or \0) in the name, with any standard, user-level programs. It doesn't matter how legacy your code is. Can you post a screen shot, or more details about where the files are coming from? Is it a samba mount for example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names

Comment: Next time, please do not cross post your question to multiple sites.

Comment: It's impossible to have the character `/` in a file name. What is the actual file name? What is the exact error message? Always copy-paste error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two characters that are *really* not allowed in a filename in unix, and you've got one of them.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457994/what-characters-should-be-restricted-from-a-unix-file-name

Are the files on a usb stick formatted as some exotic file system?  You really have to try hard to get a "/" into a filename in unix.

http://www.unix.com/tips-and-tutorials/198879-how-manage-file-names-special-characters.html has some suggestions, the easiest of which is to go back to what ever system produced the files in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop! `for F in *.csv; do gzip "$F"; done` will work because of the quotes around `$F`